# Partial evaluation of a function represented as a struct

Tags: c++, templates

In order to allow automatic differentiation, I represent a function as a struct

```
template <GLuint i>
struct x 
{
   static GLfloat eval (const GLfloat * o)
   {
      return o [i];
   }
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct ae
{
   static GLfloat eval (const GLfloat * o) {return A :: eval (o) + B :: eval (o);}
};

etc.
```

where `x <i>` denotes a parameter.

However, since I need to

1. Replace some parameters with constants at the beginning
2. When differentiating by `x <i>`, set remaining parameters at constant value

how should I implement partial evaluation, so that repeatedly passing constant arguments can be avoided and the function structure is simplified accordingly?

EDIT

We have a function

```
typedef ae <x <0>, ae <x <1>, x <2>>> f
```

I know the values of `x <1>` and `x <2>` (`c <1>`, `c <2>`).
Now I want `f` transformed into `typedef ae <x <0>, c> F`

```
struct c
{
   static GLfloat eval (const GLfloat * o) {return c <1> + c <2>;}
};
```

or something similar.

Comment: Honestly, I tried, but I have no clue what you are trying to do or what the problem is. Right now, the syntax required is something like `ae<x<1>, x<2>>::eval(ptr)`. Please elaborate on what's wrong with this, and what you would like it to become.

Comment: This can't be done using `constexpr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some syntax sugar to start.

This is a CRTP tag type.  Give it a better name:

```
template<class T>
struct my_tag {};
```

Every type that participates in this game should inherit from `my_tag<themselves>`.

Next, an `x`:

```
template<GLuint i>
struct x_t : my_tag<x_t<i>> {
  GLfloat operator()(const GLfloat * o) const {
    return o[i];
  }
};
```

notice the use of `operator()` instead of `eval`.  Next, a template variable:

```
template<GLuint i>
constexpr x_t<i> x = {};
```

we may need to add `constexpr x_t() {}` to `x_t` depending on your compiler.

This is a generic operation:

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs, class Op>
struct op : my_tag<op<Lhs, Rhs, Op>> {
  GLfloat operator()(const GLfloat* o) const {
    return Op{}( Lhs{}(o), Rhs{}(o) );
  }
};
```

and our one-line `add`:

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
using add = op<Lhs, Rhs, std::plus<>>;
```

in C++11, we have to write `std::plus<void>`.  In C++03 replace using with can instead `struct add:op<Lhs,Rhs,std::plus<>>{};` (and write `plus<>` ourselves).

Now we override `operator+` on things tagged with `my_tag`:

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
add<Lhs, Rhs> operator+( my_tag<Lhs>, my_tag<Rhs> ) { return {}; }
```

this gives us a nice algebra of operations that is less awkward to work with.

```
auto f = x<0>+x<1>+x<2>;
```

or, if we want the type

```
decltype(x<0>+x<1>+x<2>) f;
```

... ok, I've just cleaned up your system.

---

The next game is to replace variables with constants.

```
struct pi_constant {
  constexpr GLfloat operator()(const GLfloat*)const { return 3.14; }
};
```

if we want to replace our `x<i>` with that, we just have to do a search and replace of the template type.

```
template<class Target, class Pattern, class Result>
struct replace { using type=Target; }
template<class Target, class Pattern, class Result>
using replace_t = typename replace<Target, Pattern, Result>::type;

template<class Pattern, class Result>
struct replace<Pattern, Pattern, Result>{
  using type=Result;
};

template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts, class Pattern, class Result>
struct replace<Z<Ts...>, Pattern, Result>{
  using type=Z<replace_t<Ts, Pattern, Result>..., Pattern, Result>;
};
```

and `replace_t< decltype(f), x_t<1>, pi_constant >` will replace all instances of `x<1>` with the constant `pi_constant` in `f`'s expression tree.

Naturally the value of `pi_constant` has to be known at compile time.

...

Now, if you don't know the values at compile time, one approach might be to have your variables take not one, but two arrays.  Then you can use the substitute trick above to swap which of the two arrays you are reading.