# Hamiltonian mechanics-based physics engine

Tags: c++, c++11, automatic-differentiation

I am trying to implement a physics engine based around hamiltonian mechanics.
Facing several problems, such as to

1. Differentiate the H function
2. Partially evaluate a partial derivative of the H function for an efficient use of the Runge-Kutta method

I decided to represent functions as struct ([Partial evaluation of a function represented as a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059915/partial-evaluation-of-a-function-represented-as-a-struct)).

However, combining the code of C++ templates with standart C++ code proves difficult. Moreover, evaluating a struct-function appears to take at least 2× more time than a corresponding standart function.

So I ask the Stackoverflow community, whether should I keep my approach or change it.

EDIT

I use g++ and compile from command line:

g++ -std=c++14 -IC:\Hudba\include Stin.cpp Tma.cpp -LC:\Hudba\lib -lglfw3 -lglew32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lws2_32.

In order to partially evaluate a struct-function, I need to pass it an array of values that is not known at compile time, which is impossible using templates.

Comment: "combining the code of C++ templates with standart C++ code proves difficult"...how? "evaluating a struct-function appears to take at least 2× more time than a corresponding standart [sic] function" What's your code? Compiler? Compiler options? This question is impossible to answer as framed.

Comment: *"So I ask the Stackoverflow community, whether should I keep my approach or change it."* That's like asking "What's your favourite way to design this", which is (borderline) off-topic and definitely subjective.

Comment: As for the performance, have you tried enabling the optimizer?  -O3.